# How to get an element from source code Jsoup

Tags: java, html, css, jsoup

How would I go about getting the `Questions` text from this tag?

```
<li>
    <a id="nav-questions" href="/questions">Questions</a>
</li>
```

from https://stackoverflow.com/ source code as an example.

Comment: What tools do you have to get this text? If you use something like jquery (or javascript) you can just do $("#nav-questions").html();  or .text(); . You may want to get more specific with how you target this div depending what you  have on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Simply select element you want, and call `text()` method on it to get text which it generates.

In other words use something like

```
Elements anchors = document.select(cssQuerryForElementsYouWantToFind);
for(Element a : anchors){
    System.out.println(a.text());
}
```

If you have trouble with creating cssQuerry for select part take a look at http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax